# How to keep an array/linked list sorted at O(1) insertion?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I need to find an array/linked list algorithm that solve the following problem:
There are n different clubs, and there are 10 universities.
At each university there is a branch of each club.

I got k scholarship at the beginning to grant for each one of the clubs at each one of the universities. ( a total of `10*n*k`).

In addition, I can add
let's assume we can initialize any data structure at O(1) time.
we need to support the following operations:

`grant(i,j)` - grant a scholarship to the i (between 1 and n) club at the j (between 1 and 10) university. time: O(1)

`add(i,j)` - add another scholarship to the budget for the i club at the j university. time: O(1)

`insight(m)` - print the m (a number between 1 and n) clubs who had got the most scholarships until now. time: O(m)

for example, after the lines:

```
grant(1,3)
grant(1,2)
grant(2,4)
grant(2,5)
grant(3,1)

insight(2)
```

I should print:

```
club 1 got 2 scholarships
club 2 got 2 scholarships
```

I got a space complexity of O(n*k).
I need only an algorithm.

I need to use the space instead of the time to keep the data structure sorted for the insight operation but I can't find a way, because the add operation can add as many scholarships as it wants.

Comment: You cannot keep a sorted sequence in an array or linked list with only O(1) insertion time, since this would allow you to sort in O(n) time. O(n log n) is a theoretical minimum for sorting, so O(log n) is a theoretical minimum for inserting each element into a sorted data structure.

Comment: It's possible to do it using a couple of two sided linked lists and an array. The problem is that due to the add operation one of the linked list is not upper bounded. without the add operation it would have cost O(n+k) space only.

Comment: I understand that you need to keep track of the number of scholarships granted to each club via `grant(i, j)` in order to report them in `insight(m)`, but how is `add(i, j)` relevant? Your example only has `grant` and `insight`. Is it that a club cannot `grant` more times than it `add`s?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a hash set data structure with `O(1)` insertion and deletion which can be traversed (e.g. using a doubly liked list between inserted values):

I have a solution with `O(n + k)` space complexity, `O(1)` grant and `O(m)` insight. My solution ignores the university that each club belongs to since you want to sort by total scholarships awarded over all universities.

## A minor simplification

I will first give an easier to explain version with an `O(m + k)` `insight` function, before modifying it to make it `O(m)`.

### Data structures

There is a doubly linked list of hash sets, where each hash set contains the club numbers for all clubs that have given a certain number of scholarships: the first node contains all clubs that have given `0` scholarships, the seconds node for clubs that have given `1`, etc. Initially, there will only be one node in the list, with a hash set containing all the club numbers, since all club have initially given no scholarships.

There is also an array of length `n` where index `i` in the array contains the node in the aforementioned doubly linked list which has the hash set that contains club `i`.

There is also a variable to store the tail of the doubly linked list, which is where the hash set of the clubs that gave the most scholarships is stored.

### Granting a scholarship

First find the node that contains the club `i` using the array of nodes. The club is removed from the hash set of this node. If no next node exists, create it with an empty hash set, and connect it with the next and previous pointers and update the variable that points to the tail of the list. Then, add the club to the hash set of the next node in the doubly linked list.

Update the array of nodes at index `i` to point to the next node in the list.

### Insight

Use the variable that points to the tail of the double linked list to traverse the list in reverse, iterating over the hash sets and printing items until `m` have been printed.

### Complexities

The doubly linked list has a node added for each number of scholarships that have been awarded. At most `k` scholarships can be awarded so there are at most `k` Node. Each node contains a hash set, and the total number of items across all the hash sets is exactly `n`. The array is length `n`. This gives the space complexity of `O(n + k)`.

`grant` contains no loops and all operations are `O(1)`, so it is `O(1)`.

The `insight` function may be `O(m)` in some cases, such as when there are less than or equal to `m` clubs in the hash set of the tail node in the linked list, however in some cases there may be many nodes with empty hash sets that need to be iterated over to find the next item to print, for example:

```
grant(1)
grant(7)
grant(7)
grant(7)
grant(7)
grant(7)
grant(7)
insight(2)
```

This creates a linked list with the tail node just containing `7`, then (going towards the head) `4` empty nodes, then a node with `1`, then a node with all other clubs. `insight` thus may have to traverse up to `k` (the maximum length of the list) nodes, making it `O(m + k)`.

## Improving to `O(m)` insight

In order to fix this problem, each node should also contain an attribute for the number of scholarships given by the clubs in its hash set. This allows elimination of these empty nodes, since in some cases a node with only a single club in it, when it grants a scholarship may increment it's `number` rather than creating any new nodes. Unfortunately, this makes the `grant` code less neat, since now when granting a scholarship, we need to check that the number of the next node is one more than the number of the current node, and delete old nodes. This does work though, since now there are no empty nodes, so the number of nodes to iterate through is at most `m`, making `insight` into `O(m)`.

## An implementation

In case any of that wasn't clear, here is a reference implementation of the final data structure in Python:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import *


@dataclass
class Node:
    clubs: Set[int]
    number: int = 0
    prev: Optional['Node'] = None
    next: Optional['Node'] = None


class ScholarshipCounter:
    def __init__(self, n):
        # the tail of the list
        self.greatest_node = Node(clubs=set(range(n)))
        # the array pointing to the node that contains each club
        self.club_nodes: List[Node] = [self.greatest_node] * n

    def grant(self, club):
        # the node such that `node.clubs` contains `club`
        node: Node = self.club_nodes[club]

        if len(node.clubs) == 1 and not (node.next and node.next.number == node.number + 1):
            # if there is only one club, increment the number
            # unless the next node has the correct number, then add the club to that node
            node.number += 1
        else:
            # remove the club from this node so it can be added to the next
            node.clubs.remove(club)

            if not node.next:
                # create a next node if there isn't one
                self.greatest_node = Node(clubs=set(), number=node.number + 1)
                node.next = self.greatest_node
                self.greatest_node.prev = node
            elif node.next.number != node.number + 1:
                # if the number on the next node is not one more than this node's number
                # then insert a new node with the desired number in between the two
                new_node = Node(clubs=set(), number=node.number + 1)
                new_node.next = node.next
                node.next.prev = new_node
                node.next = new_node
                new_node.prev = node

            # finish moving the club to the next node
            node.next.clubs.add(club)
            # update the entry in the array of nodes
            self.club_nodes[club] = node.next

            # if the node is empty, delete it
            if not node.clubs:
                if node.prev:
                    node.prev.next = node.next
                # there is always a next node, so no need to check
                node.next.prev = node.prev

    def insight(self, m):
        return_list = []

        # iterate starting at the tail where the clubs with the most scholarships are
        node = self.greatest_node
        while len(return_list) < m and node is not None:
            # iterate over this hash set if clubs
            for club in node.clubs:
                return_list.append((club, node.number))
                # if enough have been found, stop
                if len(return_list) == m:
                    break

            node = node.prev

        return return_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sc = ScholarshipCounter(n=10)
    sc.grant(1)

    sc.grant(1)

    sc.grant(2)

    sc.grant(2)

    for i in range(10):
        sc.grant(3)

    print(sc.greatest_node)
    for club, number in sc.insight(3):
        print(f'club {club} got {number} scholarships')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy maintain a list of clubs sorted by # of scholarships.  The key is that each club's count only changes by 1 for each grant.

A data structure that works is a doubly-linked list of all the distinct scholarship counts.   The node for each count has a doubly-linked list of all the clubs that have that number of scholarships.  Each club's node has a pointer to the count node that contains its list.  You also need an auxiliary index of club node by club ID or whatever.

When you grant a scholarship:

1. Get the club's node and the containing count node.
2. Look to the count node's right.  If there's no node for count+1, then make one.
3. Move the club's node from the count node's list to the count+1 node's list.
4. If count node is now empty, delete it.

To get the m clubs with the most scholarships, you just start at the high end of the count list, and output all the clubs for each count until you have enough.